# How do I add available team members to my party?

Tags: shadowrun-dragonfall

I am trying to go see Green Winters, but none of my team follows me to the Autobahn. How do I get them to follow me? When I try to talk to them, they all just tell me they have nothing to say.

Answer (score 1):

Well your team members will not be moving with you when you are in a city hub. You have to go to a quest area for them to follow you.

Go to the Autobahn, click on the train and select the option to go to the Hotel. At this point the team selection screens will show up.